# Looking up a value in a column based on a measure in another table

Tags: powerbi

In Power BI I have a measure that calculates the average value of a column. It always contains a number between 0 and 4

```
RoundedUpAverageScore = ROUND(AVERAGE(SmileyHistory[SatisfactionLevel]),0)
```

I then have a table that consists of a score from 0 to 4 and an url.

[image: ScoreUrl]

I want to use the RoundedUpAverageScore to look up which url to use for an image in Power Bi.

Naturally I cannot make a relation between a measure and a column in Power Bi, so the two tables are currently not connected.

[image: Relations]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOOKUPVALUE` should do the trick:

Add the following MEASURE:

```
RoundedUpAverageURL = 
LOOKUPVALUE ( 
    Smileys_Sheet[Url],
    Smileys_Sheet[Score],
    [RoundedUpAverageScore]
)
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the feedback. I've just updated my question as it does not return the value it is supposed to return. It returns the very first url instead of the one that matches the Score

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a sample of your source data, with an expected outcome.

Comment: I have just edited my question and included a hardcoded number to show that it returns the correct value. I assume that is what you meant?

Comment: Which shows a) my answer does what you asked for, and b) there is something in your source data which is preventing your original `RoundedUpAverageScore` measure from returning a whole number... And I can't advise on that, without seeing your source data (table SmileyHistory). Note that formatting a decimal number as a whole number does not change the data type... You may be better using `INT ( ROUND ( AVERAGE ( SmileyHistory[SatisfactionLevel] ), 0 ) )`

Comment: You're right. I've accepted your answer as the correct as it answers the original question.

Okay thanks I will try that!

Comment: Floating Point precision means that "whole number" formatted decimal numbers don't always exactly equal integer values. To compare integers, change the data type, not just the formatting.

Comment: I have now changed all the data formats to be Integer. They are all Data Type: Whole number, Format: Whole Number. 

It still isn't working. But Perhaps I should rather make a new thread about it, as you've answered my original question.

Comment: As I mentioned, you need to return an integer value in your measure.

Comment: I am. This is what it looks like
 
RoundedUpAverageScore = INT( ROUND(AVERAGE(SmileyHistory[SatisfactionLevel]),0))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191538/discussion-between-olly-and-andreas-uldall-leonhard).